typescript union type judgment is not intuitive
type Has2<T extends readonly any[], U> = T[number] extends U ? true : never;

type UU = ['Kars', 'Esidisi'];

type AA = Has2<UU, 'Kars'>; 

I think AA should be type true, but type is never
I don`t know why
i try to ask chatGPT but it`s answer is that type AA is true

Your extends condition looks backwards to me. "Kars" | "Esidisi" does not extend "Kars", but the opposite is true.

i think T[number] get type 'Kars' | 'Esidisi' ，so the result should be true | never

When judging the extents of a union type, shouldn't it be judged separately and then combined?

Think of it like function arguments. If a function takes a string, it would be completely inappropriate to pass it a string | number, just because it's a union that MIGHT be a string.

It should be U extends T[number] https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/C4TwDgpgBAEghgZwEwB4AqUIA9gQHYAmCUceIA2gLoA0UAqgHxQC89mO+RUa5eArgFsARhABOlKAH4owUX2gAuKHggA3MQG4AUFtCR6dFlHIByANJxRCE7RMBRBAEsCjpycrbd4aAEEfR+GQUOjpbCysTBg0oLQB6WKhEgD1JIA

type Test<T, U> = T extends U ? true : never;
type Result = Test<'Kars' | 'Esidisi', 'Kars'>;
but this case, Result is true ,what`s the difference

When you index access the tuple UU (=["Kars", "Esidisi"]) in Has2 with T[number] you get an union type "Kars" | "Esidisi".
Usually, when dealing with unions assignment is only valid if the type you want to assign has fewer union members than the target type. When conditional types act on a generic type, they become distributive which is what happens here.

When conditional types act on a generic type, they become distributive when given a union type. [...] the conditional type will be applied to each member of that union.

However, you only get the distributive behavior when you pass a union type as a generic argument. You're passing a tuple.
In your example with indexed access you actually check whether "Kars" | "Esidisi" extends "Kars". Or in other words you expect "Kars" | "Esidisi" to be assignable to "Kars" which is not the case. Therefore, never is returned.
If you directly pass the union Union[number] as an argument to your generic type the condition applies to each member. That means TypeScript checks separately whether "Kars" extends "Kars" (yes => true) and whether "Esidisi" extends "Kars" (no => never). What you get as a result is true | never. Since the never type essentially represents an empty union TypeScript simplifies this to just true.
type Has_Tuple<T extends readonly any[], U> = T[number] extends U ? true : never;
type Has_Union<T, U> = T extends U ? true : never;

type Union = ["Kars", "Esidisi"];

type Result_Tuple = Has_Tuple<Union, 'Kars'>; 
//   ^? type Result_Tuple = never
type Result_Union = Has_Union<Union[number], 'Kars'>; 
//   ^? type Result_Union = true

TypeScript Playground

why this cse works
type Test<T, U> = T extends U ? true : never
type Result = Test<'A' | 'B', 'A'>   // type Result = true

Does my edit answers your question?

T[number] is also a  union type ,that  is also where I am confused

Ah, now I see what you mean. I updated my answer once more. Does it make sense to you now?
